# Vectorized hashing/ranking of integer combinations of fixed size via operations on 32-bit integers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, hash, vectorization, gpgpu, ranking

I have huge dynamically created tables/matrices in MATLAB of varying first dimension, whose rows represent (sorted) combinations of integers in the range 1-50 of order 6.

I would like to assign to each combination a unique value (hash, ranking), so that I can check if the same combinations appear in different tables. Different combinations are not allowed to have same value assigned, i.e. no collisions. I have to make a lot of such comparisons between a lot of such tables. So, for performance reasons, I would like to accomplish this by vectorization of `uint32` operations to make it suitable for GPU acceleration in MATLAB.

Things I have thought of so far:

1. Lexicographic ranking: no idea how to vectorize the standard fast recursive algorithms well, and the only option seems to be to `parfor` it through the rows, which is slower than other options. IIRC, the direct explicit formula, though vectorizable, requires computation of binomials, which in turn requires `log Gamma` function in order to avoid huge factorials + `double` type to avoid collision if I am not mistaken, i.e. is slower because it's 'very numerical'.
2. Cantor pairing function: one can successively apply Cantor's pairing, which is nice because it's a polynomial expression, but it produces huge numbers well beyond `uint32` and is definitely slower than other options.
3. Base 51 (no pun intended) integers: sends a combination/row vector `(x_1,...,x_6)` to `x_1 + x_2 * 51 + ... + x_6 * 51^5`. This is the fastest I currently have. It's easily vectorizable, but unfortunately still requires `uint64` or `double` for rank-6 combinations of 50 elements, which is slower than `uint32` or `single` type operations would be.

> So,  I guess, I am looking for a 'clever' injective function on these combinations that computes within the `uint32` range and is also well vectorizable (in MATLAB).

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** Here is a routine that benchmarks both ranking and searching in `uint32`, `single`, and `double`. I have used MATLAB's `gputimeit` to produce accurate results.

```
% testing parameters:
N = 26;
ord = 5;

% base-(N+1):
basevec_uint32 = gpuArray(repmat(uint32(N+1),1,ord).^cast(0:ord-1,'uint32'));
basevec_single = cast(basevec_uint32,'single').';
basevec_double = cast(basevec_uint32,'double').';

% highest hash value:
max_hash_value = gpuArray(cast(N-ord+1:N,'single'))*basevec_single

% benchmark GPU-accelerated base-(N+1) ranking for uint32, single, and double:
X_uint16 = randi(N,15000000,ord,'uint16','gpuArray');
X_uint32 = cast(X_uint16,'uint32');
X_single = cast(X_uint16,'single');
X_double = cast(X_uint16,'double');

Y_uint16 = randi(N,5000000,ord,'uint16','gpuArray');
Y_uint32 = cast(Y_uint16,'uint32');
Y_single = cast(Y_uint16,'single');
Y_double = cast(Y_uint16,'double');

ranking_uint32 = @() sum(bsxfun(@times,X_uint32,basevec_uint32),2,'native');
ranking_single = @() X_single*basevec_single;
ranking_double = @() X_double*basevec_double;

disp('ranking in uint32:'); gputimeit(ranking_uint32,1)
disp('ranking in single:'); gputimeit(ranking_single,1)
disp('ranking in double:'); gputimeit(ranking_double,1)

% benchmark GPU-accelerated searching in uint32, single, and double matrices:
X_uint32_ranks = myfun_uint32(); Y_uint32_ranks = sum(bsxfun(@times,Y_uint32,basevec_uint32),2,'native');
X_single_ranks = myfun_single(); Y_single_ranks = Y_single*basevec_single;
X_double_hash = myfun_double(); Y_double_ranks = Y_double*basevec_double;

search_uint32 = @() ismember(X_uint32_ranks,Y_uint32_ranks);
search_single = @() ismember(X_single_ranks,Y_single_ranks);
search_double = @() ismember(X_double_ranks,Y_double_ranks);

disp('searching in uint32:'); gputimeit(search_uint32,1)
disp('searching in single:'); gputimeit(search_single,1)
disp('searching in double:'); gputimeit(search_double,1)
```

I am using nVidia GTX 1060, which gives me the following benchmark results under Windows (I don't know, however, how much WDDM influences `gputimeit`):

```
>> test1

max_rank_value =

gpuArray single

14327680

ranking in uint32:

ans =

0.0129

ranking in single:

ans =

0.0063

ranking in double:

ans =

0.0108

searching in uint32:

ans =

0.1572

searching in single:

ans =

0.1577

searching in double:

ans =

0.1599
```

> **Conclusion:** The choice of type does not impact the GPU-accelerated search via `ismember` (expected), however there is a noticeable difference in the ranking speed coming from the matrix multiplication. Ranking in `single` is almost twice as fast as ranking in `double`, while ranking in `uint32` is nearly the same as ranking in `double`. MATLAB does not currently support GPU-accelerated `uint32` matrix multiplication, so I am using a substitute function for this. Thus, it is much more reasonable to try to encode combinations of 50 elements of order 6 as `single` values, which, if I am not mistaken, has just enough bits to accomodate all 15890700 combinations as `single` integers.

Comment: What sort of performance are you looking for? What is the best you've achieved so far?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that a base conversion is running at a few nanoseconds per row using doubles, and I'm not sure how you get much faster than that without a mex file. I mean, I can get 'clever' and do a co-lexicographic ranking using a LUT to keep values in the uint32 range, but it's an order of magnitude slower (in Octave, so MATLAB timings might be a bit different).

Comment: @beaker: thanks for the comment and apologies for the delay! Been busy these last days with exams and such. I don't remember off top of my head the exact times I measured, I have to check and come back to you.

Comment: @beaker: I have added a test routine and the corresponding benchmark results. I did use `gputimeit` to make sure that the measurements of the GPU execution times are accurate.  I don't find any difference between ranking in `uint32` and ranking in `double`, but that could also be because of the different functions since MATLAB does not support `uint32` matrix multiplication on GPU. However, there is noticeable difference between ranking in `single` and ranking in `double` - `single` is almost twice as fast. So it would make sense to look for a ranking function operating in the `single` space.

Comment: I had previously forgotten that MATLAB does not support GPU-accelerated `uint32` matrix multiplication.

Comment: Theoretically, you should be able to get more speed by performing a radix sort on the arrays and merging to find duplicates. In practice, I don't think you'll be able to match the speed of MATLAB's compiled code. `intersect` also doesn't look to be noticeably faster than `ismember`, although if you use the `rows` option with either of these you can use `uint8` arrays. The problem with the co-lexicographical ranking is that `nchoosek` is not vectorized, and indexing using each array element just bogs down the calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got enough bits for your last idea, so you just need to squeeze a few bits out due to the ordering to get it over the bar.  Since the whole sequence is sorted, every pair is also ordered.  So use a 50-by-50 look-up table to map the sorted (1st,2nd), (3rd,4th), (5th,6th) pairs into numbers from 0-1274.

Or if you don't want a table, there are fairly simple explicit functions for mapping a pair (i,j) with j>=i to a linear index.  Look up upper- or lower-triangular matrix indexing for details on those.  (It'll be something along the lines of
`n*(n+1)/2 - (n-i)*(n-i-1)/2 + j`
with some +/-1's thrown in depending on base-0 or base-1 indexing, and n=50 in your case, but I'm sure I'll get it wrong writing it off-the-cuff.)

Anyway, once you've got three numbers 0-1274, the base-1275 idea will fit in `uint32`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the cool idea and apologies for the delay! I need a little bit of time to assimilate it. I hope you won't mind if I have some follow-up questions.